# Export a page and import using SP2013 designer. all webpart missed

Tags: sharepoint-designer, export, import

[image]

I am using SP2013 Designer to export a page from site collection A and then import to site collection B. The page contain custom layout and two webparts (search result and refinement panel).

Before import, I use notepad to amend the layout path to site collection B's layout. In the file I can see some code related to those two webparts (e.g.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs1" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WpNs0" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
```

..........

```
<title>search result</title></head><WpNs0:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="__WebPartPageLibraryZone__"><ZoneTemplate><spsswc:ResultScriptWebPart runat="server" DataProviderJSON=
```

)

However, after import the page, the page is able to load up without error. But all the webparts are missed. What can be the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide some additional information of the imported file, in particular to include register directives?

Comment: I added the first few lines of imported file. Thanks!

Comment: Aha, looks like SPD incorrectly generates the namespaces in the exported file. Please try to replace spsswc:ResultScriptWebPart with WpNs1:ResultScriptWebPart, since the namespace spsswc is not registered.

Comment: I have even tried import the page back to the original site collection (using another page file name). The webparts also lost!

Comment: Vadmin I have replaced spsswc and still the same. I have several lines with tag MSO (e.g. <mso:CustomDocumentProperties> ) should I modify them?

Comment: Indeed it is, since spsswc namespace does not exists, please replace it with  WpNs1 and import the file again

Comment: No, you don't need to modify mso:CustomDocumentProperties, but please make sure you replaced all the occurrences of spsswc

Comment: Yes I have replaced all spsswc but those webpart still not showing up. The weird part is the page didn't show any error. The layout (with natvigation menu at top and left) work as usual just the webparts in the content region disappear.

Comment: What is the issue with spsswc? How can one solve this problem once and for all time?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to move a publishing page with Content Search web part from one site collection to another.This is what worked for me:

1. Export page from Source site collection using designer.
2. Replace  the tag **spsswc** with **WpNs1** .
3. Change the publishing page layout url value of property **mso:PublishingPageLayout**.
4. I uploaded the page to target site collection from browser instead of Import using designer.

I was able to see the webpart in my new sitecollection.