# Sharing Site Pages across site collections

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, site-collection

I have a root site collection where i have one site page. I want to share this site page across other site collections which will be used by my clients. i.e. suppose I make any changes to site page in root site collection, it should reflect everywhere.

How this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can create that page as Site page or application page and deploy that. In this way you can get that page across all site collections.

- [Creating Pages for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff354405.aspx)
- [Creating Application Pages for SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx)

also check this response.

[Copy a page across different site collections](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101500/copy-a-page-across-different-site-collections)

Comment: either you manully copy the page to all site collections as i mentioned in last link or you deploy as feature which update when you update the site page.