# Share Content between sites

Tags: content

I have 2 sites on sharePoint 2013 (intranet site + Internet site), each one has its own content (lists, master page, etc...) except some pages like "about us", "daily news"...

My problem is the following:

The content administrator is doing the work twice; when he wants to add/ edit those pages content he needs to add/edit it in the intranet site AND in the internet site...

Then, i want to have some solution to that allowing this user to add/edit content ine the intranet site and the content of the internet site would be updated automatically... Is there any way to do this?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: can you explain more to me please? i am new here so go on easy on me :)

Comment: This was just an suggestion on how to do it. :)

Comment: do you want same content on both sites or your both site having own content and just have couple of section which are common? both sites are in the same web application or different web application?

Comment: both site having own content and just have couple of section which are common, different web application

Comment: check this one may be that solve your problem http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101500/copy-a-page-across-different-site-collections ?\

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112426/sharing-site-pages-across-site-collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Scenario you have two options( as your both web application in same farm).

**Option 1** use the codeplex tool [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/), this tool used to move/copy content within a SharePoint environment, or across multiple SharePoint environments which are at the same version.

**Option 2** Use the [Cross-Site publishing Features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635876(v=office.15).aspx) of SharePoint 2013.Cross-Site Collection Publishing is a SharePoint Server 2013 feature that enables you to use one or more site collections to author content, and one or more site collections to control the design of the site and the display of the content. The functionality provided by this feature is referred to as cross-site publishing. You can use cross-site publishing to create branded Internet, intranet, and extranet publishing sites. Cross-site publishing is available only in SharePoint Server 2013.

check below links for more info:

http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Cross-site-publishing-for-Page-Library-in-SharePoint-2013

http://sp2013.blogspot.com/2012/10/cross-site-publishing-with-sharepoint.html

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj656774(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I have been chacking the cross site publishing for more then 2 days now ... the problem is that they display always items as list items, while i need just to display some normal text from that site into a newly created page ... :/

Comment: thnx a lot Waqas it worked

Comment: One last question Waqas please, what do you thin kis better method between SharePoint content deployment wizard and the Cross site publishing(since they can do the same thing here)?

Comment: i would prefer the OOTB funcationality(Cross Site) as you will get more support on that...