# How do roll out customize search page on all other team sites on different site collections?

Tags: search, search-results, site-collection, team-sites

I created a search page on top level of each site collection. However I would like to know how I can roll it out other team sites on different site collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Designer can be used to copy a page from a site collection *A* to a site collection *B*. This is done using the SharePoint's **Import Files** and **Export File** functionalities, which become active when you select the page you'd like to work with on SPD, as seen in the figure below.

Do **note**, that for the page you have exported from your site collection *A*, you need to do a small modification before importing it to site collection *B*. After exporting the file, open the file in an editor of your preference to find the element `mso:PublishingPageLayout`. Update the value of `mso:PublishingPageLayout` to point to your destination site collection's (*B*) Master Page Gallery. After this is done, you can move on to importing the page to your destination.

[image]

Reference: [Copy a page across different site collections](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101500/copy-a-page-across-different-site-collections).