# Copy sharepoint online Page (with webpart) in different site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I created a page under Site Contents --> Pages library in sharepoint online. This page contains Script Editor webpart. This page working as per requirement in its own site collection. When I try to copy / export / import this page in a different site collection, its not showing web part. 
Rest contents (e.g. text) of page is copying & showing in new site collection.

My question is :
Why not web part (which is added in Page) is showing in new site collection ?
How to resolve this problem ?

I followed link [Copy a page across different site collections](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101500/copy-a-page-across-different-site-collections)
but its not working for web parts added in page.

In attached screenshot (script editor), I can see "My script editor" text in new site collection but not "Hello" which is part of "Script editor web part".

[image: SiteContents]
[image: aspx page]
[image: script editor]

Answer (score 0):

Use the OOTB feature to check if it works.

[image]

Reference:

[Move or copy files in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/move-or-copy-files-in-sharepoint-00e2f483-4df3-46be-a861-1f5f0c1a87bc?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE)

[How to copy pages in SharePoint Online](https://sharepointmaven.com/copy-pages-sharepoint-online/)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried the same step & took reference of other tutorials but still unable to see web part in destination.